# R: write a loop code to go through every nth rows and do a function in datatable?

Tags: r, loops, sorting, datatable, apply

I wonder how to write a `loop code` to go through every `nth` rows and do a `function`.

for example,

1-  I'd like to `sort` descending every two lines `(#1 & #2)`, `(3&#4)` and *etc*.
2-  I'd like to calculate the `mean` of var1 for every two lines `(#1 & #2)`, `(#3&#4`) and *etc*.

For example, I'd like to order `every two rows` in `df` based on `ID` column :

```
    library(data.table)
    ID <- c("229-220", "229-27", "229-321", "229-36")
    Var1 <- LETTERS[1:4]
    Var2 <- rnorm(4,4,1)
    df<- data.frame(ID, Var1, Var2)
    setDT(df)
    df
           ID Var1     Var2
1: 229-220    A 4.497850
2:  229-27    B 2.033383
3: 229-321    C 4.701356
4:  229-36    D 3.527209
```

Expected results:

```
### for the first question I'd like to get something similar to this:
         ID    Var1    Var2
    1  229-27    B     2.033383 
    2  229-220   A     4.497850
    3  229-36    D     3.527209
    4  229-321   C     4.701356

 ### for the second question I'd like to get something similar to this:
          com              mean
          A-B             4.49785
          C-D             3.527209
```

I tried different things but was useless.

**Please Provide an answer or hint for me to get help rather than just simply downvote it!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option. We can use the `dplyr` package. The key is to use `mutate(Group = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2))` to create the group you want. `df2` is for your first desired output. `df3` is for your second desired output.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Group = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2)) %>%
  arrange(Group, desc(Var1)) %>%
  select(-Group)

df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(Group = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(com = paste(Var1, collapse = "-"),
            mean = mean(Var2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(com, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

To address your problem, you can simply do your operations by selecting every second line and comparing to the previous one... Briefly, you use seq() to get the indexes of your even lines (2, 4, 6 and so on) and you combine IDs or calculate means with the preceding rows.

```
seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2)
[1] 2 4
```

To address part 1, you could apply this strategy and order every 2-row slice of your data table according to ID.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2), (function(i){
  slice <- df[(i-1):i,]
  slice <- slice[order(slice$ID, decreasing = T),]
  rownames(slice) <- NULL
  slice
})))

        ID Var1     Var2
1:  229-27    B 3.430371
2: 229-220    A 6.201931
3:  229-36    D 4.756426
4: 229-321    C 3.467930
```

Using the same approach and lapply, this addresses mean calculation in a data.table-wise fashion.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2), (function(i){
  data.frame(com = paste(df$Var1[c((i-1):i)], collapse = "-"),
             mean = mean(df$Var2[((i-1):i)]))
})))

  com     mean
1 A-B 4.816151
2 C-D 4.112178
```

Comment: Yes you did, and I am grateful for that  but I am afraid it did not work!

Comment: I assumed so. Can you please elaborate on what error message you got or what went wrong, so we can try to help?

Comment: You want to sort based on Var1? I added that part in my answer, let me know if you get what you want! :-)

Comment: No I want to sort based on the ID, basically I wan to have the `229-27` `first` and the  `229-220` `second` and the same thing `229-36`  as `first` in its `two row sorting`  and `229-321` as the` second` and so on.

Comment: Ok. I edited according to this requirement. Let me know if it worked. cheers